# Addclass on clicked li and remove class from siblings

Tags: jquery

On click I want to add a class to an anchor tag, and remove that class from all of the siblings. However, my current code doesn't seem to remove the class from the other elements even though it does seem to add the class on click.

Here is my Code:

```js
$("ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
       $(this).children().addClass('cell-selected').siblings().removeClass('cell-selected');
    });
});
```

```css
.cell-selected { color: #fff; background: #5b2200; border-color: #ce5209; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a class="cell">Plan 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a class="cell">Plan 1.2</a></li>
    <li><a class="cell">Plan 1.3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a class="cell">Plan 2.1</a></li>
    <li><a class="cell">Plan 2.2</a></li>
    <li><a class="cell">Plan 2.3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Uploaded on http://jsfiddle.net/9wky66ju/24/

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I am having trouble understanding what your desired outcome is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/971n28hh/)***

You can use `.parent()` to get back to the siblings, but then you will need to select the class `cell-selected` in order to remove that class from those elements.

```
$("ul li").click(function(){ // don't need each (click does this internally)
 $(this).children().addClass('cell-selected') //add cell-selected class to a
 .parent() //go back to li
 .siblings() //look at siblings
 .find('.cell-selected') //find cell-selected elements
 .removeClass('cell-selected'); //remove the class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good @travis J - I needed this my self.

I've added a some more in case someone also wants to target the li element, like I wanted too.

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
 $(this).children().addClass('cell-selected')
 .parent().addClass('active').siblings().find('.cell-selected').removeClass('cell-selected')
 .parent().removeClass('active');

});
```

**[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cadima/7dr1LeLm/1/)**