# Add class for the clicked button and remove class from siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add a class to the button that is clicked and remove that class from all of the siblings(button).
The below code adds the CSS for the buttons which I click and unable to remove the CSS for the buttons that are already applied.

```js
$("#followingButtonsId").children().addClass('buttonSelected')
            .parent().siblings().find('.buttonSelected').removeClass('buttonSelected');
```

```css
.buttonSelected { background: #5b2200;}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="followingButtonsId">
    <button class="buttonSelected">Button1</button>
    <button>Button2</button>
    <button>Button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the code be in an event handler if you want it to occur based on an event occurring?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Yes. However, I just placed logic to add and remove css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Addclass on clicked li and remove class from siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224753/addclass-on-clicked-li-and-remove-class-from-siblings). In fact, the wording of the question is almost exactly the same as this one...

Comment: The above ques has li and tags but my scenario is just parent elements

Comment: Yeah, the questions have slightly different code. Yours has different class names too. But the questions are almost exactly the same other than superficialities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click I remove the class `buttonSelected` from all buttons and then add it on the one that is clicked

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  $('button').removeClass('buttonSelected');
  $(e.target).addClass('buttonSelected');
});
```

```css
.buttonSelected {
  background: #5b2200;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="followingButtonsId">
  <button class="buttonSelected">Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
  <button>Button3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("#followingButtonsId button").on("click", function() {
    $("#followingButtonsId button").removeClass("buttonSelected");
    $(this).addClass("buttonSelected");
});
```